# how to split date in one column

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I want to split date from `DATE_H_REAL` and have only date in my column

```
DATE_H_REAL             DATE_H_REAL
02/02/2016 16:17        02/02/2016
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
dataset1$DATE_H_REAL <- strptime(dataset1$DATE_H_REAL, format="%d/%m/%Y")
dataset1$DATE_H_REAL <- as.POSIXct(dataset1$DATE_H_REAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to a `Date` class, you can use `as.Date()` and precise the format of your input:

```
dataset1$DATE_H_REAL=as.Date(dataset1$DATE_H_REAL,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

This returns a date:

```
[1] "2016-02-02"
```

In case your input column doesn't have a constant format, you can first extract the date before converting it to a `Date` class:

```
dataset1$DATE_H_REAL=gsub(".*(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}).*","\\1",dataset1$DATE_H_REAL)
dataset1$DATE_H_REAL=as.Date(dataset1$DATE_H_REAL,format="%d/%m/%Y");
```

Comment: i wanna split date from time and have only date

Comment: `as.Date()` converts to a `Date` format and doesn't keep the time.

Comment: it doesn't work thats what i got 2016-02-02T00:00:00Z

Comment: Are your values in DATE_H_REAL in the format "02/02/2016 16:17" ?

Comment: You can actually just use `format = "%d/%m/%Y"`; `as.Date` will ignore anything after the tokens are matched.

Comment: yes and i want to have only " 02/02/2016 " instead of "02/02/2016 16:17"

Comment: When you simply do `as.Date("02/02/2016 16:17",format="%d/%m/%Y")`, does it still give you the error?